# Bash script to mount usb

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to have auto script to open dir on any removable device - different usb have different names and I want the user only to enter the device name since the path `/media/user` is a default in most linux systems. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
F= `zenity --entry`
mkdir /media/user/${F}/new+directory
```

The interpreter doesn't recognize the variable. Any solution / suggestions?

Comment: Remove the space after the `=` sign.

Comment: Btw, I would hate to have to enter the name in a stupid zenity box like this! Oh, and use `F=$(zenity --entry)` (with `$(..)` instead of backticks). AND USE MORE QUOTES.

Comment: Please quote that stuff: `mkdir "/media/user/$F/new+directory"`.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/375066/80864

Answer (score 2):

Running your script through [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically points out that you have a superfluous space after the = in your assignment:

```
#!/bin/bash
F=`zenity --entry`
mkdir "/media/user/${F}/new+directory"
```

Comment: It's funny how ShellCheck tells you to _Use $(..) instead of deprecated `..`_